Detailed UI requirements vs Specifying in design files (via notes, etc.)
I've been working in high-tech industrial companies for all my life, designing and specifying UIs for often very complex products. In my current job/role we did a lot of good UX stuff: competitor analysis, customer journeys, personas, low- and high fidelity designs, some user testing on them, etc. The designs I make are being implemented by a different business unit and we have our own testers that will validate the solution. I hand over my (Figma) designs to the implementation team with a few interactive sessions, and the designs have lots of sticky notes and other markup that detail required functionality. The question has come however, to formalize those remarks into a set of 'detailed UI requirements'. I've seen 2 takes on this:

Really write down UI requirements in a requirement management tool, like Doors or Jira/R4J, etc. We did this at a previous customer. Pro: requirements can be used to test against with both manual and automated test, you can do full requirements management, it aligns with development processes big companies have, etc. Con: You end up duplicating a lot of notes, requirements and mockups will start to deviate at some point, the set of requirements tend to get really long.
Don't do it, and use the designs (including all notes, markup and prototyping facilities) as leading. Developers and testers will just have to use those. Pro: you have a single source of truth, it's easier to iterate, easier to understand because it's tied to the visuals and it feels more Agile. Con: often not accepted as it does not follow company processes, people miss the traceability that they have for other system requirements etc.

What is your experience with this?

Third approach: create a manual doc similar to an instruction manual – https://haynes.com/en-us/sites/default/files/product_jackets/Haynes-10430-page-1.jpg

The new "Compare changes in Dev Mode" in Figma might be useful here. It solves the problems of - 1) Keeping track of changes 2) One source of truth. But ya, it comes with additional costs per seat as Dev Mode is not free anymore (maybe worth a try as you mentioned collaborating with big companies)

@Kish: I am currently in a 400.000+ size company, but even we have trouble justifying costs for dev mode
